# How to find and click links/buttons by href? (GeckoFx browser)

Tags: c#, geckofx

In the past I were using

```
       GeckoElementCollection elements = iframe.ContentDocument.GetElementsByName("name");
            foreach (var element in elements)
            {

                 if (element.GetAttribute("href") == "text")
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show(element.GetAttribute("class"));
                 }
              }
```

So I were finding element by name and then I checked href if its element which im trying to find.
Now I dont have any element name only class (class is same for few elements) and what is unique is href. So I need to search element by href and perform click/input events with it.

I believe that I need to use GeckoNode

```
    GeckoNode node = iframe.ContentDocument.GetElementsByClassName("classname")[0].FirstChild;
             if (NodeType.Element == node.NodeType)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(node.GetAttribute("hreff"));

             }
```

However GetAttribute dont work with nodes.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know the question is old, but today I had same problem and I fix it. Try something like this :

```
GeckoElementCollection fblikes = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
            foreach (GeckoHtmlElement item in fblikes)
            {
                string aux = item.GetAttribute("href");
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aux) && aux.Equals("p.php?p=facebook"))
                {
                    item.Click();

                }
            }
```